# swift unable to use api data in collection View

Tags: ios, swift

here my JSON is -

```
    {
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "15756323",
            "name": "A",
            "icons": "https://sdfgsuew34j.png",
            "createdAt": "2021-03-18T13:06:44.054Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-03-18T13:06:44.054Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "6053503drm476"
        },
        {
            "_id": "45646054821",
            "name": "S",
            "icons": "https://dkj/djf.png",
            "createdAt": "2021-03-19T10:51:07.066Z",
            "updatedAt": "2021-03-19T10:51:07.066Z",
            "__v": 0,
            "id": "6054821b11kd6873"
        }
]
  }
```

I'm trying to print API data in collectionView
here's some code

```
    var places: [Post]?
       func apicall() {
            
            let url = URL(string: "http://17.550.457.84/api/category/list")!
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                
                if error == nil {
    
                do {
                    self.places = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self, from: data! )
                  
                } catch {
                    print("Error during JSON serialization: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                
            }
        }.resume()
    }
```

I get a message in the debugger -> Error during JSON serialization: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

i also try to change  -> `self.places = try JSONDecoder().decode([Post].self`, from: data! )` to

```
self.places = try JSONDecoder().decode(Post.self, from: data! )
```

then I got the error -> Cannot assign the value of type 'Post' to type '[Post]?'

here my model class is

```
struct Post : Codable {
    let _id : String?
    let name : String?
    let icons : String?
    let createdAt : String?
    let updatedAt : String?
    let __v : Int?
    let id : String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case _id = "_id"
        case name = "name"
        case icons = "icons"
        case createdAt = "createdAt"
        case updatedAt = "updatedAt"
        case __v = "__v"
        case id = "id"
    }
```

Comment: Where is the guy named Post?

Comment: Can you show us your model named Post

Comment: Besides, the guy named Post should be a dictionary, not an array.

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik yes, I edit my question and update the model class in it

Comment: I update my model class, please check

Comment: i think you are not getting a valid response, i checked with your API and it show 404 error., please check again with your API

Comment: Don't print `error.localizedDescription`, instead you should print error since that gives you a much more detailed and helpful error message. So in the catch do `print("Error during JSON decoding: \(error)")`

Comment: @AnuragSoni Hopefully this is because you don't have access. OP, is that a public API? If not then I think you should remove the IP address.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson detailed error is -> Error during JSON decoding: dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})))

Comment: You should add this to the question as well. The json you have posted is valid yet the error says it isn't so you are receiving something else. Before decoding you could print it using `if let data = data { print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))` }

Answer (score 2):

The error message basically says "Your model and coming data model(JSON) are not equal". You need to change your model like :

```
struct BaseModel : Codable{
   var status : String?
   var data : [Post]?
}
```

And when you try to deserialize it you need to make a instance of that BaseModel so

```
    var baseModel: BaseModel?
    var places: [Post]?
```

when response success

```
 do {
       let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseModel.self, from: data! )
        self.places = responseData.data!
              
 } catch {              

        print("Error during JSON serialization: \(error.localizedDescription
   }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you take var data : [Post]? in struct

Comment: Response Json and your model must be equal. If its not, JSondecoder can not decode it

Comment: when I use var data : [Post]? . please tell me how to access in collectionView -> cell.lbl.text = places?[indexPath.row].name it shows me error -> Value of type 'BaseModel' has no member 'name'

Comment: @coceki If places type is BaseModel , you have to use places.data[indexPath.row].name

Comment: thanks a lot, I got the logic but I got the error in do statement -> Cannot assign value of type '[BaseModel.Post]' to type '[BaseModel]?'

Comment: and when I use the [BaseModel] instead of BaseModel  it shows the same message in debugger -> Error during JSON serialization: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Comment: @coceki We create matching model with your Json and your json has 1 object its not array.So you should not use [BaseModel].

Comment: so please tell me what I do for this error -> Cannot assign value of type '[BaseModel.Post]' to type '[BaseModel]?'