# swift Error during JSON serialization : The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to parse JSON data to collectionView, but I get errors
Error during JSON serialization: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

here is my model class

```
   struct BaseModel : Codable{
    var status : String?
    var data : [Post]?

struct Post : Codable {
    let _id : String?
    let name : String?
    let icons : String?
    let createdAt : String?
    let updatedAt : String?
    let __v : Int?
    let id : String?
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        
        case _id = "_id"
        case name = "name"
        case icons = "icons"
        case createdAt = "createdAt"
        case updatedAt = "updatedAt"
        case __v = "__v"
        case id = "id"
    }
}
}
```

here's some code

```
 var places: [BaseModel]?
 func apicall() {
        
        let url = URL(string: "http://34.335.360.24/api/category/list")!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            
            if error == nil {

                do {
                    let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode(BaseModel.self, from: data! )
                   self.places = responseData // get error on this line
                    
                } catch {
                    
                    print("Error during JSON serialization: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            
        }
    }.resume()
    }
```

i get error in do statement -> Cannot assign value of type 'BaseModel' to type '[BaseModel]?'

Comment: Don't print `error.localizedDescription`, just print `error`  You also seem to be confused as to whether your json contains a instance of `BaseModel` or an array of that struct.

Comment: You have already asked about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949239/swift-unable-to-use-api-data-in-collection-view), why post a new question when people have already tried to help you once? Also, you should really take the time to learn the basics about arrays, struct , properties etc because now it looks like you are guessing a lot. [Swift Programming Language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html) is an excellent free online book worth reading

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let responseData = try JSONDecoder().decode([BaseModel].self, from: data!)
```

Comment: when I try this then I get the message in the debugger area -> Error during JSON  The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

```
var places: [BaseModel]?
```

change above line to

```
var places: BaseModel?
```

Comment: can you tell me how to access the collectionView elements, I want to print results in collection view --->. let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! CreatGroupCollectionViewCell. let link = http://34.335.360.24/api/category/list" + places![indexPath.row].data![indexPath.row].icons!
        cell.lbl.text = places?[indexPath.row].data![indexPath.row].name
        cell.btn2.downloaded(from: link)
        return cell

Comment: it gives me the error ---> Type 'BaseModel' has no subscript members

Comment: you already ask that question before you don't know about it?

Comment: because you take a wrong array first you need to retrive post array from places(Basemodel) that use it in cell.